# Weight painting problem, smooth weights not working, the deformation is not smooth

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

[image]I have a big problem with weight painting in blender. I think the solution may be more simple than i imagine but i couldn't find a solution by myself nor on the internet.

The deformation in the model acts like the weights are red (maximum weight). It doesn't matter how much I smooth my weight paint it always acts as if the vertices are at the maximum value.

Note: The plane is high poly so the deformation should be smooth but it doesn't work.

I'll be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file or a part of it? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Are the vertices in question weighted to mulltiple bones?  Anything weighted to only a single bone may as well be fully weighted.

Comment: As Nathan says, if a vertex is parented to only one bone, even with a weight of 0.01, it will be moved by the bone as if it was weight at a rate of 1

Comment: Hello! I got it fixed, someone told me to add weight to the main bone used to move the entire model even if it's parented to the rest of the bones and it works now! 
Thanks a lot for the answers!