# Armature Weight Paint - Not Easing, not smooth, 1 to 100, not stretching, deform not smooth, deform not easing

Tags: armature, bones

I have applied armature to a mesh and modified the weight paint. When I pose the armature, it doesn't deform the mesh smoothly. If the weight is greater than 0.001 then it seems to deform it 100%.

How can I get this to deform smoothly?

[image: h]

Comment: Weights are relative to other weights.  If a vertex is weighted 1.0/1.0 to two bones, or 0.5/0.5, or 0.0001/0.0001, the weights are the same: the vertex is *equally* weighted to both bones.  Likewise, if a vertex is weighted only to a single bone, it doesn't matter what its weight is, because the relative value here is 0: even 0.0001/0 is fully weighted; *all* of its weight is on its one bone, regardless of what number that is.  If you want to see the effects of gradated weights, you need at least two bones.

Comment: Solution found here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230265/weight-painting-problem-smooth-weights-not-working-the-deformation-is-not-smoo

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some weight for these vertices to another bone. For example, you could use the root bone and add a very small amount of weight for these vertices.

They will then have a *relative weight* on the bone you want to move, compared to the root bone, and should deform correctly.